# How to make a searchable list from Json?

Tags: json, list, search, swiftui

I have a Json list with Airports that I can view in a list.

Json list:

```
[
  {
    "name": "Hartsfield Jackson Atlanta Intl",
    "city": "Atlanta",
    "country": "United States",
    "iata_code": "ATL",
    "_geoloc": {
      "lat": 33.636719,
      "lng": -84.428067
    },
    "links_count": 1826,
    "objectID": "3682"
  },
  {
    "name": "Chicago Ohare Intl",
    "city": "Chicago",
    "country": "United States",
    "iata_code": "ORD",
    "_geoloc": {
      "lat": 41.978603,
      "lng": -87.904842
    },
    "links_count": 1108,
    "objectID": "3830"
  },
]
```

My Code is like this:

```
struct Model: Codable, Identifiable, Hashable {
    enum CodingKeys: CodingKey {
        case name
        case city
        case country
        case iata_code

    }

    var id = UUID()
    var name, city, country, iata_code: String
}

class Json: ObservableObject {
    @Published var json = [Model]()

    init() {
        load()
    }

    func load() {
        let path = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "Airports", ofType: "json")
        let url = URL(fileURLWithPath: path!)

        URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url) { (data, responce, error) in
            do {
                if let data = data {
                    let json = try JSONDecoder().decode([Model].self, from: data)

                    DispatchQueue.main.sync {
                        self.json = json
                    }

                } else {
                    print("no Data")
                }

             } catch {
                print(error)
            }

        }.resume()
    }
}
```

And Body:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @ObservedObject var Airport = Json()
    var body: some View {

        List(Airport.json) { item in

            VStack(alignment: .leading) {
                Text(item.iata_code)
                Text(item.name)
            }

        }
    }
}
```

This gives me a list with Iata codes and Airport names.

My question is, how can I make this list searchable? by name, code or other. 
I want to make something similar to travel agacys. Im new to SwiftUI. 
Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create something like this:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @ObservedObject var Airport = Json()

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            TextField("Search for names", text: $Airport.searchText)
            List(Airport.searchResults.isEmpty ? Airport.json : Airport.searchResults) { item in

                VStack(alignment: .leading) {
                   Text(item.iata_code)
                   Text(item.name)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

```
class Json: ObservableObject {
    @Published var json = [Model]()
    @Published var searchText: String = "" {
         didSet {
            // Here comes your search condition...
            self.searchResults = self.json.filter { $0.name.starts(with: self.searchText) }
            // Uncomment the line below if you want to accept that the word you're typing in is the middle on the name
            // self.searchResults = self.json.filter { $0.name.contains(self.searchText) }
         }
    }
    @Published var searchResults: [Model] = []

    init() {
        load()
    }

    func load() {
        let path = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "Airports", ofType: "json")
        let url = URL(fileURLWithPath: path!)

        URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url) { (data, responce, error) in
            do {
                if let data = data {
                    let json = try JSONDecoder().decode([Model].self, from: data)

                    DispatchQueue.main.sync {
                        self.json = json
                    }

                } else {
                    print("no Data")
                }

             } catch {
                print(error)
            }

        }.resume()
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your help. How ever, now I get an error: Cannot convert value of type 'Binding<[Model]>' to expected argument type 'Binding<String>' in the textfield line?

Comment: Oops check the answer now

Comment: Thank you! now the error is gone, but I still can't search in the list... I can type in the text field, but it does not seem to do anything. the ".filter" gets a cation message " Result of call to 'filter' is unused " may this have something to do with it?

Comment: now it should work hehe. I'm typing it here and not in Xcode that's why

Comment: now there are no errors, but still don't work. been playing with the code all day.. do you have any idea what can be wrong? as far as I can tell, there is some miss-communication between the text field and the search results? when I remove the if statment and only apply the "Airport.searchResults" the list is empty, even when searching.

Comment: Have you printed what the filtered search results gives you in the didSet?

Comment: when I print(searchText) I get the name I am searching for, when I print print(searchResults) I get [ ]. and when I print(self.searchResults.filter) I get "(Function)"

Comment: Same results, when searching nothing changes on the screen. and when printing I get "(Function)"

Comment: can you host the project on github

Comment: Never Used Github, so let me know if this is not working. https://github.com/BlondePK/JsonTest

Comment: Repo is empty.. Watch a yt video how to push it there

Comment: Yes I was to fast, here it is. https://github.com/BlondePK/AirportList

Comment: Yes! now its working, very slow.. but thats a different issue. Thank you

Comment: Please mark this answer as solved by the checkmark and give a upvote.